# Issue with flutter pub get

Tags: flutter, dart, get

Recently when I do `Flutter pub get`, I receive the following error.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.3.8/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:340:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'scrollBehavior'.
              scrollBehavior: scrollBehavior,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:167:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` first and then maybe try replacing the version number of GetX package with any temporarily so you don't have any conflicts (if any).